# How to set first photo for cover by plupload

Tags: javascript, php, plupload, uploader

I use [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) for uploading pictures. How can I set first image to upload which would be cover photo? How can I change order of added photos for uploading?

Comment: please provide us with some code you have already wrote

Comment: a put it below as an answer. I need to select somehow first photo for upload. It always goes with an order of selecting.

Answer (score 0):

```
   // Upload Form
                                    $(function () {

                                        // Settings ////////////////////////////////////////////////
                                        var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
                                            runtimes: 'html5,flash,silverlight', // Set runtimes, here it will use HTML5, if not supported will use flash, etc.
                                            browse_button: 'pickfiles', // The id on the select files button
                                            multi_selection: true, // Allow to select one file each time
                                            container: 'uploader', // The id of the upload form container
                                            resize: {quality: 70},
                                            max_file_size: '5000kb', // Maximum file size allowed
                                            url: 'upload1.php', // The url to the upload.php file
                                            flash_swf_url: 'js/plupload.flash.swf', // The url to thye flash file
                                            silverlight_xap_url: 'js/plupload.silverlight.xap',
                                            init: {
                                                FilesAdded: function (up, files) {
                                                    plupload.each(files, function (file) {
                                                        if (up.files.length > 10) {
                                                            up.removeFile(file);
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                    if (up.files.length >= 10) {
                                                        $('#pickfiles').hide('slow');
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                FilesRemoved: function (up, files) {
                                                    if (up.files.length < 10) {
                                                        $('#pickfiles').fadeIn('slow');
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            },
                                            // The url to the silverlight file
                                            filters: [{title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,gif,png"}] // Filter the files that will be showed on the select files window

                                        });


                                        // Start Upload ////////////////////////////////////////////
                                        // When the button with the id "#uploadfiles" is clicked the upload will start
                                        $('#uploadfiles').click(function (e) {
                                            uploader.start();
                                            e.preventDefault();

                                        });

                                        uploader.init(); // Initializes the Uploader instance and adds internal event listeners.

                                        // Selected Files //////////////////////////////////////////
                                        // When the user select a file it wiil append one div with the class "addedFile" and a unique id to the "#filelist" div.
                                        // This appended div will contain the file name and a remove button
                                        uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function (up, files) {
                                            $.each(files, function (i, file) {
                                                $('#filelist').append('<div  class="addedFile" id="' + file.id + '">' + file.name + '<a href="#" id="' + file.id + '" class="removeFile"></a>' + '</div>');
                                            });
                                            up.refresh(); // Reposition Flash/Silverlight
                                        });

                                        // Error Alert /////////////////////////////////////////////
                                        // If an error occurs an alert window will popup with the error code and error message.
                                        // Ex: when a user adds a file with now allowed extension
                                        uploader.bind('Error', function (up, err) {
                                            alert("Error: " + err.code + ", Message: " + err.message + (err.file ? ", File: " + err.file.name : "") + "");
                                            up.refresh(); // Reposition Flash/Silverlight
                                        });

                                        // Remove file button //////////////////////////////////////
                                        // On click remove the file from the queue
                                        $('a.removeFile').live('click', function (e) {
                                            uploader.removeFile(uploader.getFile(this.id));
                                            $('#' + this.id).remove();
                                            e.preventDefault();
                                        });


                                        // Progress bar ////////////////////////////////////////////
                                        // Add the progress bar when the upload starts
                                        // Append the tooltip with the current percentage
                                        uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function (up, file) {
                                            var progressBarValue = up.total.percent;
                                            $('#progressbar').fadeIn().progressbar({
                                                value: progressBarValue
                                            });
                                            $('#progressbar .ui-progressbar-value').html('<span class="progressTooltip">' + up.total.percent + '%</span>');
                                        });

                                        // Close window after upload ///////////////////////////////
                                        // If checkbox is checked when the upload is complete it will close the window
                                        uploader.bind('UploadComplete', function () {
                                            if ($('.upload-form #checkbox').attr('checked')) {
                                                $('.upload-form').fadeOut('slow');
                                            }
                                            window.location.href = "goToNew.php";
                                        });

                                        // Close window ////////////////////////////////////////////
                                        // When the close button is clicked close the window
                                        $('.upload-form .close').on('click', function (e) {
                                            $('.upload-form').fadeOut('slow');
                                            e.preventDefault();
                                        });

                                    }); // end of the upload form configuration
```